# Default dowloaded folder path of Google drive api v2

Tags: c#

What is the default download folder path in the computer using this code? How could i retrieve the file downloaded? I've been trying to find the file successfully downloaded using this code. I do know the filename of the file from the google drive so basically if I search the whole computer drives, I do have a better chance of finding it. But the opposite is getting me bugged down.

```
        var fileId = "0B4qGWGglUVhZTXVxeXM";
        var request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
        var streams = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
            {
                switch (progress.Status)
                {
                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                            Console.Read();
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                            Console.Read();
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                            Console.Read();
                            break;
                        }

                }
            };
        request.Download(streams);
```

Comment: I seriously doubt you'll find file stored in `MemoryStream`... Not really sure what you expect to happen - consider [edit] the post to explain what behavior you expect (so far question is somewhat unclear because of that).

Comment: This question is pretty unclear. Could you perhaps try editing it to help us understand what you are wanting?

Comment: You already answered my question. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

`streams` will contain the downloaded file. Its up to you where you want to write that file on your disk.

Use the following code to write it the disk

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\folder\path\file.ext", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)) 
{
  byte[] bytes = new byte[streams.Length];
  streams.Read(bytes, 0, (int)streams.Length);
  file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  streams.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is standard code that will write nothing to the output file. Make sure to try it out and than fix it.